# I've been triying to get data from website with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Firstly, I tried a lot of ways but I couldn't solve my problem. I don't know how to place my node way in SelectSingleNode(?) method. I create a html path to reach my node in my c# code but if I run this code, I take NullReferenceException because of my html path. I just want you that how can I create my html way or any other solution?
This is example of html code:

```xml
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="box">
                <div class="box">
                    <div class="boxContent">
                        <div class="userBox">
                            <div class="userBoxContent">
                                <div class="userBoxElement">
                                    <ul id ="namePart">
                                        <li>
                                            <span class ="namePartContent>

                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this my C# code:

```
namespace AgilityTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri url = new Uri("https://....");
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string html = client.DownloadString(url);
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(html);

            string path = @"//html/body/div[@id='container']/div[@id='classifiedDetail']"+
                "/div[@class='classifiedDetail']/div[@class='classifiedDetailContent']"+
                "/div[@class='classifiedOtherBoxes']/div[@class='classifiedUserBox']"+
                "/div[@class='classifiedUserContent']/ul[@id='phoneInfoPart']/li"+
                "/span[@class='pretty-phone-part show-part']";
            var tds =  doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(path);
            var date = tds.InnerHtml;

              Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take as an example your `namePartContent` span node. If you want to fetch that data you would simply do this:

`doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='namePartContent']")?.InnerText;`

It will search/fetch a single span node with `namePartContent` as its class, begining at the root node, in your case `<html>`;